# Why is "from ... import *" in a function not allowed?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, python-import

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement):

> The wild card form of import — `from module import *` — is only allowed at the module level. Attempting to use it in class or function definitions will raise a `SyntaxError`.

Why? What's the sense of avoiding to use it in a function? What's the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CPython implementation uses a special optimisation for local variables:  They aren't dynamically looked up at runtime from a dictionary, as globals are, but rather are assigned indices statically at *compile time*, and are looked up by index at runtime, which is a lot faster.  This requires the Python compiler to be able to identify all local names at compile time, which is impossible if you have a wildcard import at function level.

In Python 2, there was still a fallback mechanism that got invoked in cases where it wasn't always possible to determine all local names statically.  This mechanism used a dynamic dictionary for local variables, significantly slowing down execution.

For example this code

```
def f():
    exec "x = 2"
    print x
```

works as expected in Python 2, whereas

```
def f():
    exec("x = 2")
    print(x)
```

results in a `NameError` in Python 3.

Comment: So if I'm getting it the right way: during the compiling time, for local scopes, Python locates all the variables used and stores them in a table; instead for globals Python modifies the dictionary that contains all global names at runtime. In a function we can't use the wildcard because, using Python a static mechanism, then it should find and compile all the modules imported in the functions and those modules imported in those modules. Is that right?

Comment: @antox: Yes, that's right.  And since global variables are dynamic, they can even be dynamically created at runtime, e.g. by modifying the `globals()` dictionary or by using `exec()`, so it's outright impossible to statically determine all the names that might get imported.

Comment: @sven_marnach Ok, just one question. You said that in Python2 they used a double mechanism, the first static and the second dynamic as a fallback. Couldn't they use a sort of this behavior for globals too? beause I understand that 'statically' optimazes the program, so they use a static strategy, but in case you wanna do `exec("x=2")` the engine falls back on the second strategy

Comment: I mean, is the dynamic mechanism that slows down or is the entire mechanism of switching from static to dynamic mechanism that slows down?

Comment: @antox: Implementing this for globals is difficult to do without changing language sematics.  E.g. you would have to detect statically whether someone is calling `globals()`.  Moreover, it will probably pay off less for globals, since most variable look-ups in loops are for locals.  If you want to micro-optimize your code, you can lift global variables into the global scope.